PDF print garbled after update to Ubuntu 22.04
Printing to my Lexmark E342n laser printer worked fine until I recently.  Now when I try to print a PDF file of sheet music I get an error message
*** Error: Tf refers to an unknown source name: f-0-0 Assuming it's a fo
followed by a page of incorrect print - the staves are present but the notes only print the tails, the key signature and clef are missing etc. In short, garbage.
I printed out a web page, with photos and text, to check. That worked fine apart from some streaks on the photos. Apparently it's just the music PDF.
I tried another SSD drive with a newly installed Ubuntu, but it's exactly the same.
Hopefully it will work again when I install the next Ubuntu, on another drive.

Have you tried 24.04?

Not yet. I will do that when I get my new drive. But I am annoyed that an intermediate upgrade within 22.04 messes up the printing.

My HP M255dw fails to print some pdfs on 22.04. Same pdfs print on Windows. The page prints with some ps message "ERROR: undefined OFFENDING COMMAND: image".
